# Relative line offsets in awk (/pattern/+1 or /pattern/-1)

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

When I want to print lines between two patterns, excluding the lines with those patterns, I can do it in `ex` using `+1` and `-1` after the pattern. That is awesome. Is this possible in `awk`? Right now, I kludge it by setting an `is_printing` flag.

This is `ex` to get the column definitions from an SQL table creation:

```
$ ex schema/media.sql <<< '/^CREATE TABLE/+1,/^)/-1p'
#        id
#                SMALLINT
#                UNSIGNED
#                NOT NULL
#                AUTO_INCREMENT
#                COMMENT 'The auto-generated ID.',
#        parent_id
#                SMALLINT
#                UNSIGNED
#                NULL
#                COMMENT 'The ID of the parent album, if any.',
#        title
#                VARCHAR(255)
#                COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
#                NOT NULL
#                DEFAULT ''
#                COMMENT 'The album title.',
#        description
#                TEXT
#                COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
#                NOT NULL
#                COMMENT 'The album''s description.',
```

This is an `awk` command to do the same:

```
$ awk '/^\)/ { exit; } is_printing; /^CREATE TABLE/ { is_printing = 1; }' schema/media.sql
```

I find the awk version not as readable. Is there an idiom I am missing? Can `sed` do something like this, too? (I prefer `awk`'s syntax over `sed`'s.)

Comment: This shows the basic technique: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22568/4801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but awk cannot do so, because each line is seperately passed through the script.

Theoretically it would be possible to implement an *+x*, turning a line match after *x* more input lines to true, but I don't think I'd like to debug such scripts ;-)

BTW: Although everything may be placed on the same line, I'd vote for a new line at least for every condition/action pair, so scripts are far easier to read and understand.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I do the `+1` offset with a `next`, but the `-1` would require keeping a buffer. Too bad.

Comment: For the record: I completely agree re: readability and can assure you my actual `awk` scripts are properly formatted. It does underscore the neatness of the `ex` way for a simple one-liner, though.

Comment: I'll leave this open for another day in case someone might come up with a `sed` way, but given the whopping 18 views so far, I don't think it likely… Thanks for your answer!