# How to run grep and show x number of lines before and after the match

Tags: bash, grep

`grep` returns just the line where it matched the regex and often what I want to really see is a few (say 2) lines above and below the matched one.
Is there a simple way to achieve it?

EDIT:
OS: Ubuntu based Bodhi Linux. 
As mentioned in comments, -C does not work in vanilla but its GNU grep in my case.

Comment: See [Show lines matching a pattern and the 4 lines before each](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/show-lines-matching-a-pattern-and-the-4-lines-before-each) and [How to display lines 2-4 after each grep result?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31531/how-to-display-lines-2-4-after-each-grep-result). Certainly we have answers point to the `-C` option too, but can not find it…

Comment: Does your grep recognize -C2?

Comment: @Kevin yes it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `man grep`:

> Context Line Control
>
> -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>
> Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a
>   line containing  a  group  separator (--)  between  contiguous  groups
>   of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect
>   and a warning is given.
>
> -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
>
> Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a
>   line containing  a  group  separator (--)  between  contiguous  groups
>   of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect
>   and a warning is given.
>
> -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
>
> Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing a group
>   separator (--)  between  contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or
>   --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

See how easy that was?  `man` is your friend.

Comment: That is for GNU grep, vanilla Unix grep hasn't got those.

Comment: @vonbrand That I did not know.

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (more portable) :

```
awk '
    {
        arr[NR]=$0
    }
    END{
        for (i=0;i<=NR;i++) {
            if (arr[i] ~ grep){
                for (j=i-count; j<=i+count; j++) {
                    print arr[j]
                }
            }
        }
    }
' grep=kdm count=4 /etc/passwd
```

I grep user `kdm` againts `/etc/passwd` with 4 lines before/after the match

In a [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) script :

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '
    {
        arr[NR]=$0
    }
    END{
        for (i=0;i<=NR;i++) {
            if (arr[i] ~ grep){
                for (j=i-count; j<=i+count; j++) {
                    print arr[j]
                }
            }
        }
    }
' grep="$1" count="$2" "$3"
```

Usage :

```
./contextgrep <pattern> <count> <file>
```