# grep: Always show context of N lines

Tags: grep, osx

Given a file like

```
asdasd
123
X
456
X
789
asd
asd
asd
asd
```

If I run grep: `grep -C3 'X'` on the above, I get the following results

```
asdasd
123
X
456
--
456
X
789
asd
asd
```

It appears that grep only shows the context of each match up to the previous or following match. Is there a way to get it to display the entire context regardless of whether the pattern is contained in it? Looking at `man grep`, there seems to be no such option. The expected result is as follows:

```
asdasd
123
X
456
X
789
--
123
X
456
X
789
asd
asd
```

Comment: What version of OSX are you running, and what does `grep --version` report?  The (admittedly very old) Mac I just tried came with GNU grep 2.5.1, which produces something else again (the first 8 lines of the file, with no `--`).

Comment: if you okay with awk, you could adapt the second solution present in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66196/how-to-run-grep-and-show-x-number-of-lines-before-and-after-the-match for your needs

Comment: `grep --version` reports "grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD". Running on MacOS Mojave Version 10.14

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short perl script to do it. It does read the whole file into memory, so might not be appropriate for really big files.

```
perl -0777 -snE '
    @lines = split /\n/;
    for $idx (grep {$lines[$_] =~ $p} 0...$#lines) {
        say join "\n", @lines[$idx-($n-1) .. $idx+($n-1)], "--";
    }
' -- -n=3 -p='X' file
```