# Delete range of lines above pattern with sed (or awk)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

I have the following code that will remove lines with the pattern `banana` and 2 lines after it:

```
sed '/banana/I,+2 d' file
```

So far, so good! But I need it to remove 2 lines **before** `banana`, but I can't get it with a “minus sign” or whatever (similar to what `grep -v -B2 banana file` should do but doesn't):

```
teresaejunior@localhost ~ > LC_ALL=C sed '-2,/banana/I d' file
sed: invalid option -- '2'
teresaejunior@localhost ~ > LC_ALL=C sed '/banana/I,-2 d' file
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unexpected `,'
teresaejunior@localhost ~ > LC_ALL=C sed '/banana/I,2- d' file
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown command: `-'
```

Comment: The easiest is to load all the data into an array, skip the undesired lines then output what remains: `awk '{l[m=NR]=$0}/banana/{for(i=NR-2;i<=NR;i++)delete l[i]}END{for(i=1;i<=m;i++)if(i in l)print l[i]}'`. This is not efficient, so this is just a hint, not a solution.

Comment: Just do `tac file | sed ... | tac`. :P

Comment: @angus I didn't think about it ;)

Comment: you could have done `sed '/banana/,+2d' file`  that will also work

Comment: If you're open to using awk, it's pretty simple:  `awk 'tolower($0)~/bandana/{print prev[!idx];print prev[idx]} {idx=!idx;prev[idx]=$0}' filein`  Since this is a comment and not an answer (there are already other answers), I won't go into too much detail, but the crux of it is you always have the previous two records in prev[0] and prev[1], the "freshest" depending on which iteration but always in `prev[idx]`, so when you print, you print in `!idx` then `idx` order.  Regardless, alternate `idx` and put the current record in `prev[idx]`.

Comment: A good read with many examples:
http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/sedfaq.txt

Comment: I'm curios about what does `I` do in `'/banana/I,+2 d'`. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sed doesn't backtrack: once it's processed a line, it's done. So “find a line and print the previous N lines” isn't going to work as is, unlike “find a line and print the next N lines” which is easy to graft on.

If the file isn't too long, since you seem to be ok with GNU extensions, you can use `tac` to reverse the lines of the file.

```
tac | sed '/banana/I,+2 d' | tac
```

Another angle of attack is to maintain a sliding window in a tool like awk. Adapting from [Is there any alternative to grep's -A -B -C switches (to print few lines before and after )?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/is-there-any-alternative-to-greps-a-b-c-switches-to-print-few-lines-before/11201#11201) (warning: minimally tested):

```
#!/bin/sh
{ "exec" "awk" "-f" "$0" "$@"; } # -*-awk-*-
# The array h contains the history of lines that are eligible for being "before" lines.
# The variable skip contains the number of lines to skip.
skip { --skip }
match($0, pattern) { skip = before + after }
NR > before && !skip { print NR h[NR-before] }
{ delete h[NR-before]; h[NR] = $0 }
END { if (!skip) {for (i=NR-before+1; i<=NR; i++) print h[i]} }
```

Usage: `/path/to/script -v pattern='banana' -v before=2`

Comment: `sed` can do sliding windows too, but the resulting script is typically so unreadable that it's easier to just use `awk`.

Comment: @Gilles.. The `awk` script is not quite right; as-is it prints blank lines and misses the last lines. This seems to fix it, but it may not be ideal or right itself: `if (NR-before in h) { print...; delete...; }` ... and in the `END` section: `for (i in h) print h[i]` ... Also, the awk script prints the matching line, but the `tac/sec` version does not; but the question is a bit ambiguous on this..  The "original" awk script, to which you provided a link, works fine.. I like it...  I'm not sure how the above 'mod' affects the *print after* lines...

Comment: @Peter.O Thanks, the awk script should be better now. And it took me less than 6–8 years!

Answer (score 24):

This is pretty easy with **ex** or **vim -e**

```
    vim -e - $file <<@@@
g/banana/.-2,.d
wq
@@@
```

The expression reads: for every line containing banana in the range from the current line -2 to the current line, delete.

What's cool is that the range can also contain backwards and forwards searches, for example this will delete all sections of the file starting with a line containing apple and ending with a line containing orange and containing a line with banana:

```
    vim -e - $file <<@@@
g/banana/?apple?,/orange/d
wq
@@@
```

Also note that up to ten vim/ex commands can be submitted using the inline command option "-c".  See the man page.

```
vim -e -c 'g/banana/.-2,.d' -c 'wq' $yourfilename
```

and

```
ex -c 'g/banana/?apple?,/orange/d' -c 'wq' $yourfilename
```

Comment: Is that dot after `g/banana/` necessary? Can't/shouldn't it be `g/banana/-2,.d`

Comment: . refers to the current line, so ".-2" is 2 lines before the match. ".-2,." is the range of lines from 2 lines before the match to the line containing the match. I'm not sure if that first . is required though

Answer (score 10):

You can do this fairly simply with `sed`:

```
printf %s\\n    1 2 3 4match 5match 6 \
                7match 8 9 10 11match |
sed -e'1N;$!N;/\n.*match/!P;D'
```

I don't know why anyone would say otherwise, but to *find a line and print previous lines* `sed` incorporates the built-in `P`rint primitive which writes only up to the first `\n`ewline character in pattern space. The complementary `D`elete primitive removes that same segment of pattern space before recursively recycling the script with what remains. And to round it off, there is a primitive for appending the `N`ext input line to pattern space following an inserted `\n`ewline character.

So that one line of `sed` should be all you need. You just replace *`match`* with whatever your regexp is and you're golden. That should be a very *fast* solution as well.

Note also that it will correctly count a *`match`* immediately preceding another *`match`* as both a trigger to quiet output for the previous two lines *and* quiet its print as well:

---

```
1
7match
8
11match
```

In order for it to work for an *arbitrary* number of lines, all you need to do is get a lead.

So:

```
    printf %s\\n     1 2 3 4 5 6 7match     \
                     8match 9match 10match  \
                     11match 12 13 14 15 16 \
                     17 18 19 20match       |
    sed -e:b -e'$!{N;2,5bb' -e\} -e'/\n.*match/!P;D'
```

---

```
1
11match
12
13
14
20match
```

...deletes the 5 lines preceding any match.

Comment: what does ```-e:b``` here do? I was trying to delete 4 lines of stuff off my xml file which has ```<tag>
something I want to match; 
next line something i want to match; 
</tag>``` and i could not get it working

Comment: Regarding your line sed -e'1N;$!N;/\n.*match/!P;D', if I want to have just one line above I would remove the 1N. The !N must remain because of the \n?

Answer (score 7):

Using the "sliding window" in `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'push @lines, $_;
          splice @lines, 0, 3 if /banana/;
          print shift @lines if @lines > 2
          }{ print @lines;'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `man 1 ed`:

```
str='
1
2
3
banana
4
5
6
banana
8
9
10
'

# using Bash
cat <<-'EOF' | ed -s <(echo "$str")  | sed -e '1{/^$/d;}' -e '2{/^$/d;}'
H
0i


.
,g/banana/km\
'm-2,'md
,p
q
EOF
```