# With grep, how can I match a pattern and invert match another pattern?

Tags: grep

With `grep`, I want to select all lines that match a pattern, and that don't match another pattern. I want to be able to use a single invocation of `grep` so that I can use the `--after-context` option (or `--before-context`, or `--context`).

`-v` is not viable here, as it negates all patterns I pass to `grep` using the `-e` option.

#### Example

I want to look for lines matching `needle`, ignoring lines matching `ignore me`, with one line of following context.

Here's my input file:

```
one needle ignore me
two
three
four needle
five
```

The output I want is:

```
four needle
five
```

As you can see, this naive solution doesn't work:

```
$ cat file | grep --after-context=1 needle | grep -v 'ignore me'
two
---
four needle
five
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have GNU grep, you can use [Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), which have a [negation construct](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f!pattern)).

```
grep -A1 -P '^(?!.*ignore me).*needle'
```

If you don't have GNU grep, you can [emulate its before/after context options in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/is-there-any-alternative-to-greps-a-b-c-switches-to-print-few-lines-before/11201#11201).

```
awk -v after=3 -v before=2 '
/needle/ && !/ignore me/ {
    for (i in h) {
        print h[i];
        delete h[i];
    }
    until = NR + after;
}
{
    if (NR <= until) print $0; else h[NR] = $0;
    delete h[NR-before];
}
END {exit !until}
'
```

Answer (score 8):

You appear to be using GNU [grep](/questions/tagged/grep). With GNU grep, you could pass in the `--perl-regex` flag to activate PCRE and then supply a negative lookahead assertion, example below

```
grep --after-context=1 \
--perl-regex '^(?:(?!ignore me).)*needle(?:(?!ignore me).)*$' file.txt
four needle
five
```

The main thing of note here is that `(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`

Comment: @1_CR... Sir.. it's awesome.. :P something smiler  to `ack`

Comment: @RahulPatil. :-), yes GNU grep is that good.

Comment: That's not quite what I want. I want it to work whether "ignore me" is before or after "needle".

Comment: @RahulPatil, thanks, i fixed it in the latest version

Comment: Very useful. Especially in the case of grep with context where you wish to exclude closely matching lines but without a certain part of the pattern. Close to original question but not quite the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using awk instead as it handles multi-line IO better. Either **1)** Pipe the results to GNU awk with `--\n` as the record separator, or **2)** Do all of the matching in awk.

**Option 1**

```
<file grep -A1 needle | awk '!/ignore me/' RS='--\n' ORS='--\n'
```

Output:

```
four needle                                                                                  
five
--
```

Note, this option searches the whole record for `ignore me`, set `FS=1` and match against `$1` to only compare to the first line.

**Option 2**

```
<file awk 'a-- > 0; $0 ~ re1 && $0 !~ re2 { print $0; a=after }' re1=needle re2='ignore me' after=1
```

Comment: Is there multiple `ignore me` in file then , awk not works

Comment: @RahulPatil: could you rephrase or add more detail to your question? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Thos test your example with this input file http://paste.ubuntu.com/6252860/

Comment: @RahulPatil: I see what you mean now, **Option 1** assumes that a `--\n` delimiter is between each matched group, which is not there if the groups are adjacent to each other. How adjacent groups should be handled is task-specific, so this is not necessarily wrong. **Option 2** does not depend on the separator and is not affected.