# combining grep ignore and matches

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I would like to grep a file to find all instances of the text `fn1` that don't have the word `call` in front of it and print out four lines before and after the matches (even if the surrounding lines have the word `call` in them). I tried

```
grep -A 4 -B 4 '[^call].+fn1'
```

but it doesn't get any matches (presumably because of the `[^call]`). I cannot just use -v and pipe that that to another grep or vice versa because I want to see the surrounding lines of text. I guess I could use -v on `call`, pipe that to `grep fn1` and then pipe those lines to another instance of grep that matches the whole lines with context but that seems ugly and might be really slow if there are a lot of matches.

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm not sure. Any help?

EDIT:

Sample data

```
main code
main code
more main code
call fn1(ii, jj)
even more main code
call fn2
still more main code

function fn1
call fn3
fn1 code
more fn1 code
```

I would like grep to retutn

```
call fn2
still more main code

function fn1
call fn3
fn1 code
more fn1 code
```

I want it to show me all the instances where fn1 is used *except* when it's being called and I don't want to miss other functions that are being called within the context.

Comment: can you show your input data??

Comment: some sample data w/ this Q would probably make light work of getting it resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added an example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: To clarify: `[^call]` *does not mean* everything except the word `call`. It means any character except `c`, `a` or `l`.

Comment: Similar/same question. Better answers though. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96480/with-grep-how-can-i-match-a-pattern-and-invert-match-another-pattern

Comment: This works for me: grep -B4 -A4 -P '^(?:(?!call)).*fn1' sample.txt

Comment: . . . but 4 lines of context before function call would also include the "even more main code" line. -B3 would give the sample shown in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To negate regular expressions is not easy. You could use [negative lookbehinds](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444):

```
$ grep -C4 -P '(?<!call).*fn1' test.txt 
5-even more main code
6-call fn2
7-still more main code
8-
9:function fn1
10-call fn3
11-fn1 code
12-more fn1 code
```

This `grep` uses Perl-style regular expressions (`-P`) to look for any instance of `fun` not preceded by `call`. And you can combine `-A4 -B4` to get `-C4`.

Comment: that doesn't work ?

Comment: @gaoithe are you telling me or asking me? Does your grep support PCRE?

Comment: Yes. perl-style supported. That doesn't work for me. I am asking does it work for you? This works for me: grep -B4 -A4 -P '^(?:(?!call)).*fn1' sample.txt

Comment: @gaoithe very strange, you're right. I'll have to test around to see how I got this to work.

Comment: your answer is along the right lines, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96480/with-grep-how-can-i-match-a-pattern-and-invert-match-another-pattern good explanation. Using "negative lookahead assertion". They describe it as "The main thing of note here is that (?:(?!STRING).)* is to STRING as [^CHAR]* is to CHAR".